# d3fc - Add two discontinuityProvider's

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3fc

Is it possible to add 2 discontinuityProvider's together? Something like this:

```
const xScale = fc.scaleDiscontinuous(d3.scaleTime())
    .discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuityRange([start,end]))
    .discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuitySkipWeekends());
```

My plan is to use the .discontinuitySkipWeekends() provider and the range to hide all holidays from the chart. If not would I have to create my own provider?

Comment: Found any ideas/solution? I am looking for a solution for this same use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of d3fc - unfortunately at the moment we do not support this. I've raised an issue:

https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/issues/1246

We'll look into whether we can add this features.